# Not able to Use Resolve in Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular-routing

I want to load object before the view is rendered in angular4, so i choose to use resolve of angular4 but i am not able to get data, dont know what am i doing wrong.

**this is my module**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { ActivatedRoute, Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { ResolverService } from './resolver.service';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: AppComponent, resolve: { transaction: ResolverService } }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [ResolverService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**my resolver service**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class ResolverService implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(function () {
        observer.next(150)
      }, 1000);
    });
  }  
}
```

**this is my component**

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, APP_INITIALIZER, InjectionToken, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Resolve, RouterStateSnapshot, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { student } from './sa-model.service';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(success => {
      debugger;
      console.log(success);
    })
  }

}
```

but in the component i was expecting to get the value 150 which i am passing in the resolver service, but i am not getting any values

can any one guide me on what exactly am in doing wrong

Comment: any console errors?

Answer (score 1):

It's because you opened the observable but never completed it before returning it, so nothing gets returned. Add this:

```
setTimeout(function () {
  observer.next(150);
  observer.complete(); // Need to call complete once done.
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Are you stealing my answer? :D What a ahame

Comment: No. Your answer wasn't even on my screen when I started reviewing this question. Also, my answer is better and more accurate. =)

Comment: God sees everything

Comment: Good. Then he'll see that I'm right and you're not. ;)

Comment: This `complete()` here is hardly usable in practical cases. I am pretty sure OP will use  `take(x)`

Comment: complete() is usable in many practical cases. Most likely, you are using it incorrectly.In any case, the point is not about which method is better worse, etc. it's that the observable must be complete. smh you don't give up do u

Comment: Well you are amazing. Why down-voted me?  Have you ever did something with Resolver? `complete()` has many good use cases, but not here (at least as I dont imagine those). You can use it, of course, but `take(1)` would be much shorter.

Answer (score 1):

Use `take()` ir `first()`:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<any> {
  return new Observable(observer => {
    setTimeout(function () {
      observer.next(150)
    }, 1000);
  }).take(1);
}
```

You cant pass open Observable in Router