# How to read a value from resolve in angular4

Tags: angular

i am using resolve to load data before the view is rendered in angular4.
i followed this [stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48424163/not-able-to-use-resolve-in-angular-2) and built my application but i am not able to get the result.

**resolver**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Resolve, ActivatedRouteSnapshot } from '@angular/router';

@Injectable()
export class Books implements Resolve<any> {
  constructor() { }

  resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot) {
    return new Observable(observer => {
      setTimeout(function () {
        observer.next(150);
        observer.complete();
      }, 1000);
    });
  }
}
```

**my component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(success => {
      debugger;
      console.log(success)
    })
  }
```

when i debug inside the ngOninit, i get an empty object, i was expecting a value 150
[image]

**UPDATE 1 - my routing config**

```
export const appRoutes: Routes = [
    {
        path: '',
        component: AppComponent,
        resolve: {
            users: Books
        }
    }
];
```

Comment: Please add your routing configuration

Comment: i have added my route config, could you please let me know, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a path defined to use that resolver? For example, here is one of mine:

```
  {
    path: ':id',
    component: ProductDetailComponent,
    resolve: { product: ProductResolver }
  },
```

You then read the resolver data using the name specified in the resolve above.

For example, here is mine:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    // Watch for changes to the resolve data
    this.route.data.subscribe(data => {
         this.onProductRetrieved(data['product']);
    });
}
```

It seems that yours should be something like this:

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(success => {
      debugger;
      console.log(success[yourNameHere]);
    })
  }
```

Comment: i have a route configuration in the same way you have declared, but as i have shown in the example, i am getting an empty object, please see my routing in the updated question of mine

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. If you want to build a plunker or stackblitz that demonstrates the issue with a minimum amount of code, we can take a look.